# Who Can Help Retag This?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-clues, anagram, acrostic

> Gestures to stop Jacks' paving stones
>
> Oh! Tiny reformation chaos at data transmission
>
> Occasion (the first) to initiate moderator election
>
> Circular execution of queer joshes up with issue
>
> Rearrangement of a sodium unit
>
> Even thou imp, ... our wit!
>
> Encryption device by jerk confuse implicit problem
>
> Puzzle rejection twice by chickpeas
>
> Sail man mixing with creatures

<sub>For those who recognised this at once, please consider leaving it to fellow puzzlers. Thanks! 
Working for [Generalist Countdown](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/generalist-countdown?cb=1) - [anagram](/questions/tagged/anagram)
Edited to retag (pun intended, or maybe not `;)` )</sub>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Combined with @jafe's extra solutions, we now have a complete set of answers to the clues. These are:

> Cryptic crossword clues, all of which lead to names of puzzle tags on this site

Solutions as follows...

1. Gestures to stop Jacks' paving stones (solved by @jafe)

> FLAGS – triple definition: checkered flag, Union Jack, paving stone

2. Oh! Tiny reformation chaos at data transmission

> INFORMATION-THEORY - an anagram of 'Oh! Tiny reformation' (implied by 'chaos')

3. Occasion (the first) to initiate moderator election

> TIME - meaning 'Occasion', taken as *the first* letters of **t**o **i**nitiate **m**oderator **e**lection

4. Circular execution of queer joshes up with issue (solved by @jafe)

> JOSEPHUS-PROBLEM – anagram of "joshes up" + problem (issue)

5. Rearrangement of a sodium unit

> ANAGRAM - meaning 'Rearrangement': a + Na (symbol for Sodium) + gram (a unit of measurement)

6. Even thou imp, ... our wit!

> HUMOR - meaning 'wit', taking the *even* letters of t**h**o**u** i**m**p, ... **o**u**r**

7. Encryption device by jerk confuse implicit problem (solved by @jafe)

> ENIGMATIC-PUZZLE – Enigma (encryption device) + tic (jerk) + puzzle (to confuse)

8. Puzzle rejection twice by chickpeas

> NONOGRAM - NO + NO (rejection x2) + GRAM (a variety of chickpea)

9. Sail man mixing with creatures

> ANIMALS - meaning 'creatures', an anagram of 'Sail man' (implied by 'mixing')

As for the question of 'who' can help, @jafe has also spotted that

> The initials of the answer tags anagram to 'athin' and 'jafe' (two PSE users)

Bonus:

> The initials of the clues in the first place could anagram to PSE CORE, GO! A possible call to arms for regular users of this site??

Comment: 8 is (rot 13 ababtenz)

Comment: @Sid - literally just solved that one myself too! Great minds :)

Comment: all right so far, but there is more to this...

Comment: The question is "who", so maybe it's a person or persons we're looking for. The first letters of the answers anagram to rot13(nguva & wnsr). The first letters of the *clues* are "goo creeps", which almost sounds like it should be an anagram of something as well, but if it is I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Hmmm... I did wonder. Couldn't spot anything in the solution acrostic but that sounds like a possibility @jafe...

Comment: @Stiv well done! You got the users right! actually the "goo creeps" acrostic were meant to be a red herring, nice construction tho! the green check is on its way :)

Comment: Thanks OmegaKrypton, but the credit for spotting the users definitely belongs to @jafe - appropriately, given the answer! :)

Answer (score 12):

Stiv found the correct theme. Just to fill in the rest of the clues:

1. Gestures to stop Jacks' paving stones

> FLAGS – triple definition: checkered flag, Union Jack, paving stone

4. Circular execution of queer joshes up with issue

> JOSEPHUS-PROBLEM – anagram of "joshes up" + problem (issue)

7. Encrpytion device by jerk confuse implicit problem

> ENIGMATIC-PUZZLE – Enigma (encryption device) + tic (jerk) + puzzle (to confuse)

8. Puzzle rejection twice by chickpeas

> NONOGRAM – 2x "no" (rejection) + gram (chickpeas)

Comment: Nice work @jafe - I was so sure 7 would turn out to be rot13(cnffjbeq) I was blind to anything else!

Comment: @Stiv Thanks! Feel free to incorporate these into your answer so that there's a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks jafe - will do... :)

Comment: all right so far, but there is more to this...

Answer (score 4):

## Partial Answer

I'm probably on the entirely wrong end of the field, but eh.

---

Could

> each line be referring to a certain letter?

For example:

`Occasion (the first) to initiate moderator election`

> **O** (first letter of "Occasion") — **o**pen (initiate) **o**fficials' (moderator) **o**pportunity (election)

`Circular execution of queer joshes up with issue`

> **R** — **R**ound (circular) **r**ealisation (execution) **r**um<sup>1</sup> (queer) **r**idicule (joshes) **r**ark (issue) 
>  <sub>${}^1$See [2nd definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=deifne+queer&rlz=1C5CHFA_enAU841AU841&oq=deifne+queer&aqs=chrome..69i57l2j69i59l2.1960j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#dobs=rum)</sub>

`Even thou imp, ... our wit!`

> **Y**? **Y**ou (thou) **y**uck? (imp) ??? The ellipsis might refer to another word needed to be put there, perhaps? Too much speculation here, so I'll move on.

`Puzzle rejection twice by chickpeas`

> **S** — **S**tump (puzzle) **s**nub (rejection) **s**pitting image? (twice) **s**eeds (chickpeas).

`Sail man mixing with creatures`

> **H** — **H**elm (sail) **h**uman (man) **h**ybridise (mixing with creatures).

If I *am* on the right track, then

> from the letters thus far (O, S, R, H, Y) and seeing how I got to these, the missing tag might be [steganography](/questions/tagged/steganography) because it has these letters and my answer being intended would imply the use of this tag. Perhaps the act of finding these letters would be related to a particular anagram (of them)? Not sure.

I don't want to continue with what I'm doing all the way through, however, in fear that it might be a waste of time. Hope I'm going somewhere with this :P

Comment: jafe and Siv have been all right so far, but there is more to this...